GoogleAuth getting "invalid grant: Bad Request" in call to LocalWebserverAuth()
Here's a Python script in its entirety:
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LoadClientConfigFile("client_secrets.json")
print(f'==== called LoadClientConfigFile', flush=True)
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()  # Prompt for authentication via web browser

When I run it, I get the following:
==== called LoadClientConfigFile
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\r\.virtualenvs\pygmu-oJfXpe_C\Lib\site-packages\pydrive\auth.py", line 475, in Refresh
    self.credentials.refresh(self.http)
  File "C:\Users\r\.virtualenvs\pygmu-oJfXpe_C\Lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 545, in refresh
    self._refresh(http)
  File "C:\Users\r\.virtualenvs\pygmu-oJfXpe_C\Lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 761, in _refresh
    self._do_refresh_request(http)
  File "C:\Users\r\.virtualenvs\pygmu-oJfXpe_C\Lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 819, in _do_refresh_request
    raise HttpAccessTokenRefreshError(error_msg, status=resp.status)
oauth2client.client.HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant: Bad Request

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\r\Projects\pygmu\t1.py", line 6, in <module>
    gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()  # Prompt for authentication via web browser
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\r\.virtualenvs\pygmu-oJfXpe_C\Lib\site-packages\pydrive\auth.py", line 120, in _decorated
    self.Refresh()
  File "C:\Users\r\.virtualenvs\pygmu-oJfXpe_C\Lib\site-packages\pydrive\auth.py", line 477, in Refresh
    raise RefreshError('Access token refresh failed: %s' % error)
pydrive.auth.RefreshError: Access token refresh failed: invalid_grant: Bad Request

Given that the error happens after the call to LoadClientConfigFile(), I suspect the issue might be with the call to LocalWebserverAuth().
Any ideas on how to diagnose and/or fix this?
Update
Note that no web server window appears, so I'm not sure where the problem lies.
Environment

Python 3.12
Windows 11 Pro, v 23H2
Available Browser(s): Firefox, Chrome, Edge

Update 2
Based on a hint from @LindaLawton-DaImTo, my code may be out of date.  I'm revisiting https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/about-sdk and https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/js to make sure I'm using the current API.  Standby...

didnt they remove LocalWebserverAuth?  what api are you trying to connect to?

@LindaLawton-DaImTo Trying to access Google Drive files, so Google Drive API.  I'm basing this on code that worked ten months ago.  Is there an updated tutorial or example?

are you creating an installed app or a web app?   by web app are you using fast api or flask or something?

This will be for a CLI app.

Error indicates that you aren't accessing correctly. Check your client_secrets.json is correct, or you're inputting your credentials in the web browser correctly.

Added a relevant update...

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
